# Getting the expiration date for Google Play In-App Subscriptions

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, subscriptions

The implementation of the new in-app subscription product for Android apps seems identical to regular managed/unmanaged products, but (afaik) getting the expiration date for subscriptions is only available through the Google Play Android Develope HTTP-based API.  That part has me clueless.

Any implementation examples using the Google APIs Java Client Libraries for getting the expiration date would be a huge help.

Comment: Hi, do you got any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can always calculate the expiration date using the AIDL for subscriptions. If you request `RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS` (assuming you have no previous local data) you'll get the purchase date and the current state of the the subscription and a couple of other data. If you have a monthly subscription and you are far beyond the first month you have to check current state (which could be automatic using receivers for `PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGE` pushes from Play Store). Knowing the state and purchase date you can calculate the expiration date.

Comment: Is there any in built method for getting expire date?